# How can I stop reading from a file?

Tags: c, file

How can I make it stop when I'm end of the file?
txt file is look like this;

2 4

5 6

7 8

but it prints

2 x  , 4 y

5 x  , 6 y

7 x  , 8 y

1429697293 x  , 4199392 y

```
int x[20];
int y[20];
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("coord.txt", "r");


for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    if((x[i]=='\0')||(y[i]=='\0')) break;
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &x[i],&y[i]);

}

for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        if((x[i]=='\0')||(y[i]=='\0')) break;
        printf("%d x  , %d y \n",x[i],y[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `while(i < 20 && fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &x[i],&y[i]) == 2)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just wrote

```
   while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &x[i],&y[i]) != EOF)
   printf("%d x  , %d y \n",x[i],y[i]);
```

instead of everything and it works.

Comment: Note the additional required condition within the `while()` loop in the comment by @WeatherVane  You must protect the array bounds as well as validate the `fscanf()` return. And you must validate the `fscanf()` return against the number of conversions specified, not `EOF`